# Spring JDBC with Tomcat DBCP and multiple datasources

Tags: java, spring, multiple-databases, spring-jdbc

I am using spring with have multiple datasources (catering to multiple mysql dbs) and using tomcat dbcp. I am getting some weird exceptions like

- procedure not found - when the proc is definitely  present in the db
- cannot borrow from pool - local dev setup, so definitely the pool is not full

the Problem I feel might be this, need inputs from everyone:

I have one `jdbcTemplate` object defined in my `spring.xml`, on every query that I need to fire, I call `jdbcTemplate.setDataSource()` to set the appropriate datasource and then use `simplejdbccall(jdbctemplate)` to execute the proc.

Should I go in for also defining multiple `jdbcTemplate` objects, i.e. one for each datasource defined. The bean from where I am setting the datasource on the `jdbctemplate` and executing the stored proc is defined as `prototype`.

Comment: If you aren't providing synchronization around the data access operations when you are changing the dataSource, this is horribly thread-unsafe.

Answer (score 5):

You should certainly not use a shared a `JdbcTemplate` if you're going to keep changing its `DataSource`. Set the `DataSource` once, and leave it alone.

That either means multiple `JdbcTemplate` beans, one for each `DataSource`, or create new `JdbcTemplate` objects manually, on demand, and don't share them.  There's no significant performance overhead in creating new ones, do that's not an issue.

You could define them as `prototype`, sure, but there's not much point if you're going to inject the `DataSource` manually. Might as well instantiate `JdbcTemplate` using `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer. I have got past those errors by creating a new instance of jdbctemplate everytime. I have also updated to the latest mysql jconnector jsr (5.1.14) 
The class design is now pretty simple. I have a base dao which uses a new instance of a custom written spring jdbc wrapper which in turn instantiates a jdbcTemplate object as an instance variable. This instance variable is used in a new instance of a SimpleJdbcCall for every request. all my dao classes inherit from this base dao.

However there are some intermittent errors like this :

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetadata ....
.
.
.
caused by :
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.checkConnection() : 
connection is closed.
I don't see a pattern for this error. I have an initialSize of 10 for each of the datasources & a maxActive of 100. any tips regarding what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Spring has some level of native support for switching the data sources dynamically. [Here is the article on](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) how you do it.

Below also can help

1. [Hibernate, Spring and multiple DataSources part 1](http://sysin.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/hibernate-spring-and-multiple-datasources-part-1/)
2. [Hibernate, Spring and multiple DataSources part 2](http://sysin.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/hibernate-spring-and-multiple-datasources-part-2/)