# What is the meaning of this error "org.hibernate.MappingException: Same physical table name reference several logical table names:"

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

Can somebody explain what is the meaning of this error?

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Same physical table name reference several logical table names:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your database table is defined more than once (in `.hbm.xml` or using annotations). It could well be accidental if your classloader sees too much resources.

Comment: Do you think this is happening because i have two persitence unit configured in my app both had reference to jar-file which only contains entity beans?

Comment: It could be. I suggest to eliminate one and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried to remove the redudency but now it throws PersistenceException saying it can not create ENF. I loved spring for many reason but never thought that configuring multiple persistence unit would be that difficult. Also there is not enough documentation available or even in books like Spring in Action didnt mention anything.

Comment: Try to search on SO, this topic has been discussed already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692402/spring-jdbc-with-tomcat-dbcp-and-multiple-datasources (and others)

Comment: I really appreciate your unending support for this query for this is really very frustating when I configure two emf, each with separete db and pu and all I want to do is inject them in my two diff BaseDao classes. I searched SO and found couple of discussion and based on this info I am configuring spring and pu, but no success. Can you point me to an example which can work out of the box and do some tweaking on it.

Comment: You might want to create another question providing as much details as you can as this is now quickly rolling to off-topic (hint: title of original question). Btw, appreciation is best shown in upvotes and answer accepts :)